What is the best approach to implement autosave of multiple records?
We need to implement an autosave feature for a form, saving the information every 5 seconds.
For instance, when a user clicks the "Create Order" button and starts adding line items, the form captures these details. Given the potential size of the form, we've opted to store the details every 5 seconds to ensure data is not lost.
However, a challenge arises regarding how the backend API should handle updating existing line items versus creating new ones. Our application uses React in the frontend and Rails in the backend API.
One approach to address this challenge is as follows: When the frontend sends an array of line items to the backend, it appends a temp_id to each line item. The backend then checks if each line item has an ID value, which corresponds to the primary key of the line item in the database. If the ID is not present in the database or the ID key is not in the payload, the backend creates a new record in the database and returns the temp_id generated by the frontend along with the real primary key for that line item. The front end can then use this information to update the temp_id with the real database ID sent by backend and in the next request frontend passes that db id to the API.
Is this approach reasonable, or are there better ways to handle this problem?
